Weighted isodiametric problem
This question was asked by someone on here a while back, and it got some attention but was then suddenly deleted. I am however still curious about this, so I decided to ask it again.
The question is as follows: among all plane regions $R$ of diameter $1$, is there one which maximizes the integral
$$
\iint_R d(\mathbf{x}, \partial{R}) \, d\mathbf{x} \;?
$$
Some comments:

Since taking convex hulls does not inrease diameter, we may assume $R$ is convex.
The disc of radius $1/2$ gives an integral of $\pi/24$ (and it seems likely that this is the solution).
Someone commented on the deleted post that the Reuleaux trianle gave a value $< \pi/24$.
If we replace the integrand $1$, this is solved by the isodiametric inequality, see
p. 32 of Littlewood's Miscellany (or this note) for a nice short proof.



Every convex set of diameter $s$ has width $\le s$ in every direction and, thereby, perimeter $\le \pi s$ (Crofton). 2) For $t\ge 0$ the set $R_t={x\in R: d(x,R^c)\ge t}$ is a convex set of diameter $\le 1-2t$ (triviality). 3) $\int_R dx=\iint d\ell_t,dt$ where $d\ell_t$ is the length measure on $\partial R_t$ (half-obvious). 4) Estimate as above and conclude. I'm not sure why the question had been deleted in the first place (probably, there are too many self-proclaimed "discussion policemen" around), but it's not something that requires any deep thinking anyway :-) Merry Christmas!


@fedja nice argument, thanks! This also seems to generalize to the case where the integrand is replaced by $f(d(x, \partial{R}))$ for some (say  continuous) $f: [0,1/2] \to [0, \infty)$. Do you know if this proof can be adapted to prove a weighted isoperimetric inequality? I.e. can we show by some other means that the perimeter of $R_t$ is $\leq (1-2t)\pi$ in that setting? And merry Christmas to you too!
